# How do you get a JSON object from a string in nlohmann json?

Tags: c++, json, string, nlohmann-json

I have a string that I would like to parse into a json, but `_json` doesn't seem to work every time.

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
    // Works as expected
    json first = "[\"nlohmann\", \"json\"]"_json;
    // Doesn't work
    std::string s = "[\"nlohmann\", \"json\"]"_json;
    json second = s;
}
```

The first part works, the second throws `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::type_error'
  what():  [json.exception.type_error.302] type must be string, but is array`.

Comment: Have you tried [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example2.md) it parses json directly into C++ objects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding `_json` to a string literal instructs the compiler to interpret it as a JSON literal instead.

Obviously, a JSON object can equal a JSON value, but a string cannot.

In these cases, you have to remove `_json` from the literal, but that makes `second` a string value hiding inside a JSON object.

So, you call `json::parse`, like this:

```
std::string s = "[\"nlohmann\", \"json\"]";
json second = json::parse(s);
```

[How to create a JSON object from a string.](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/681)